# How to activate not default Bootstrap tab from outer page?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have which have two links. First goes to page with default activated tab, and second link - to second tab.

I alway get default tab activated.

Here is my js code(opens tab #home):

```
$('.activate_tab').click(function(e){
  $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show');
});
```

tried also(not doing anything):

```
$('.activate_tab').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show');
});
```

and my default Bootstrap HTML code:

```
 <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="reports active left"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" >Details</a></li>
  <li class="reports right not_active" ><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Analytics</a></li>
 </ul>
 ...
 <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">//default
 ...
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">//not default
 ...
 //link on other page, which should activate default( home )tab
  <a href="/websites/4">http://super.com</a> 
 //link on other page, which should activate not default tab
   <a href="/websites/4" class="activate_tab"><img alt="" height="19" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/analytics.png" ></a>
```

What I'm missing guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my link:

```
  <a href="/websites/4#profile" class="activate_tab">aaa</a>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
var activeTab = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']');
activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');

$('.activate_tab').click(function(e){
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home">//default
 ...
 <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">//not default
```

or you can try on your second link page

```
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(1) a').tab('show');
```

Comment: but then I will make profile tab default, yes ? but I won't make first link - open first tab, second link - second tab.

Comment: I will change question. Something like this. Look again.