# Using Twitter Bootstrap Nav Tabs with Jade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, pug, nav

I cant understand why I cant make a bootstrap nav tab pane work properly using jade.

Here is my code:

```
head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='public/styles/bootstrap.css')
body
    div.tabbable.tabs-below
        div.tab-content
            div.tab-pane.active
                block content
        ul.nav.nav-tabs
            li.active 
                a(href='../', data-toggle='tab') Home
            li
                a(href='../about', data-toggle='tab') About
            li
                a(href='../blog', data-toggle='tab') Blog
            li
                a(href='../faq', data-toggle='tab') FAQ
            li
                a(href='../terms', data-toggle='tab') Terms
            li
                a(href='../privacy', data-toggle='tab') Privacy
            li
                a(href='../jobs', data-toggle='tab') Jobs
            li
                a(href='../press', data-toggle='tab') Press
    script(src="public/js/lib/jquery.js")
    script(src="public/js/lib/bootstrap.js")
```

I get the folllowing error in my console when clicking on 'About': Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ../about in jquery.js:4421

Without the data-toggle attributes it works. However, it doesn't show which tab is selected!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with jade being the view engine. It is because a new page is  being loaded and not a nested div in div.tab-content.

Solution: [How to activate not default Bootstrap tab from outer page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419939/how-to-activate-not-default-bootstrap-tab-from-outer-page)